# C# API PUT method without writing all the parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm creating a C# net.core 3.1 API and I have the next model:

```
public class Note
{
    public string noteID { get; set; } 
    public string noteTitle { get; set; }
    public string noteContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime createDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? latestEditDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to create a put model where you don't have to pass id, and datetime parameters. I have the next api put method:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutNote(string id, Note note)
{
    if (id != note.noteID)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    note.latestEditDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    _context.Entry(note).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!NoteExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return Ok(true);
}
```

When I do a PUT method I have to write all the parameters (noteID, noteTitle, noteContent, createDateTime, latestEditDateTime) but I only want to pass the noteTitle and noteContent. The createdDateTime value is written in the post method and the latestEditDateTime should be written in the PUT method.

Comment: I am confused how you expect `if (id != note.noteID)` to work without passing up the `noteID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new class and put the parameters you want to pass in it, when you receive the parameters you can pass them via automapper or by assigning them one by one

Answer (score 0):

Post or put, you can overload the params.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddNote(string noteTitle, string noteContent)
{
 ...Generate a new note stuff the content and save it
}
```